# Kotlin Serialization For this type of data structure?

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

Is it possible to use Kotlinx serialization in order to use this type of JSON data structure:

```
  {
    "USA": {
        "first_name": "Tom",
        "last_name": "Sawyer"
    },
    "UK": {
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Doe"
    },
    "Canada": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe"
    }
  }
```

To create this type of model:

```
val contactPersonMap: Map<String, ContactPerson> = ????
```

Or does anyone have a different approach in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `kotlinx.serialization` would do the job:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*

@Serializable
data class ContactPerson(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)

fun main() {
    val countryContacts = mapOf<String, ContactPerson>(
        "USA" to ContactPerson("Tom", "Sawyer"),
        "UK" to ContactPerson("Jane", "Doe"),
    )

    val jsonString = Json.encodeToString(countryContacts)
    println("jsonString: $jsonString")
    val deserializedCountryContacts = Json.decodeFromString<Map<String, ContactPerson>>(jsonString)
    println("deserialized: $deserializedCountryContacts")
}
```

Output is:

```
jsonString: {"USA":{"firstName":"Tom","lastName":"Sawyer"},"UK":{"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Doe"}}
deserialized: {USA=ContactPerson(firstName=Tom, lastName=Sawyer), UK=ContactPerson(firstName=Jane, lastName=Doe)}
```

Comment: It was that simple. I feel silly now. Thanks so much for clearing this up!

Comment: No reason to feel silly. I guess sometimes we're used to so much needless complexity and ceremony that it seems surprising how easy things can be with well designed tools – language and libraries in this case.